# Alternative to expensive disposable floor mats for taking care of recurring puddle next to toilet?

Tags: cleaning, bathroom, smell

Some men with Parkinson's disease have very poor aim when urinating. This can be a sensitive subject, such that asking the person with Parkinson's to implement one of [these ideas](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/10531/how-can-i-prevent-pee-from-flying-off-target) is not an option (and neither is installing a urinal).

The result: a recurring puddle on the floor next to the toilet, that soaks into the grout. It's unpleasant to have to clean it every evening, and the smell doesn't really go away.

Apparently one can buy [disposable floor mats](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007JLSLJU) for this purpose, and I ordered one to try, but

1. they are very expensive. I am on a budget, and this will be a long-term problem so the cost will add up, and
2. I would prefer something whose shape and size I can customize (the puddle is always in the same spot).

What can I put in that spot to make this recurring puddle less smelly and easier to clean without breaking the bank?

Comment: Some towels you wash?

Comment: Could you ask the individual to sit? Does the individual know this is happening and is apathetic?

Comment: @Stan That's the first answer to the question I linked to in my post, where I said "This can be a sensitive subject, such that asking the person with Parkinson's to implement one of [these ideas](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/10531/how-can-i-prevent-pee-from-flying-off-target) is not an option"

Comment: Leave a few tablespoons full of Baking Soda where the liquid pools to neutralize the uric acid. Periodically, bleach to disinfect. When the question arises, involve a psychologist.

Comment: Puppy pads cut to fit around toilet is what I am trying

Comment: Well, I understand that it can be a sensitive subject, but Parkinson’s affects so many things in daily life that discussing how to deal with the restrictions and side effects will have to be an (ongoing, as the condition progresses) subject anyway. Just deal with it under the premise of “how can _we_ deal with it, how can we make _you_ (= the sufferer) more comfortable”.

Comment: I suggest you bring this (unresolved?) question/issue to a companion StackExchange site: https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com which might be better suited for resolving "sensitive subjects." Good luck.

Comment: paparazzo suggested doing what I would do. Towels. Fold them up however you want,and just put them there

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why I didn't think of this earlier.

I am a private pilot. I fly alone most of the time. I'm the only pilot aboard all of the time. When I have to pee, I cannot just get up and go to a restroom - there's none in a small plane. It's impractical to land to use a restroom which might be far away or in a big crowded airport. I can't just pull over into a rest area.

When I first asked about the issue, I was introduced to a "Pilot's Comfort Station" which comes packaged for the great relief of either male or female pilots.

[Spruce Aircraft supplies](http://www.aircraftspruce.ca/menus/ps/urinals.html) [image: Pilot's Comfort Station]

These are for big boys and girls. They are not expensive. They can be cleaned easily. They can be re-used before emptying. They can be sealed against spills due to tipping. They don't take up much space. They can be carried into a bedroom. They are odour free when used according to instructions. There are no consumable expenses. They come in any colour. They can be ordered discreetly online. They will be delivered in plain packaging.

They are also called a portable urinal.

Comment: Long distance truckers also use them. Being stuck in city traffic with a full "tank" will make a convert of the owner of a strong bladder.

Answer (score 2):

Most stores that sell restroom accessories (local to me, J.C. Penney, Target or Kmart, as examples) have small horseshoe shaped rugs, made to fit around the base of a toilet stool.  These will soak up the misses as well as the disposable pads, and are washable.

Couple that with applying a sealant to the flooring around the commode, to keep the urine that gets through the rug from soaking into the grout, and you should be covered without spending a mint on disposable absorbents.

Comment: Seems like those would get smelly pretty quickly, though. I don't really want to do laundry every evening, either.

Comment: Get a half dozen or so of the rugs (under $5 each, last I looked) and an airtight hamper for them only.  Wash them once a week.

Comment: And consider a water-proof layer under the rug.

Comment: @Stephie "Couple that with applying a sealant to the flooring around the commode" -- already addressed.

Comment: I noticed. Just thought a layer of foil would reduce the frequency of scrubbing the floor.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the disposable Under Pads, referred to as ["chucks"](http://demandware.edgesuite.net/sits_pod22/dw/image/v2/AALX_PRD/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-tena_master/default/dw84637f41/354-355_US_prod_ExtraProtectionUnderpads.png?sw=556) in hospitals and doctor's offices:

[image]

They are lightweight, absorbant, and disposable.

GoToMedSupply.com has them listed at a 10-pack for $1.86. 
Tena, maker of adult incontinence products, offers a free trial kit.

See other options [here.](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en-US&oe=utf-8&safe=images&q=hospital%20chucks&source=browser-type&qsubts=1466533429929&devloc=0)

Hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Use cat litter. Seriously. It's great at soaking up liquids and absorbing odours.

Now I can understand that the person would feel offended, so you could try putting it in pillow case, and after disposing of the litter washing it like regular pee-soaked cloth.

Disclaimer : above techniques untested.

Answer (score 0):

There are many urination devices (or stand-to-pee devices) for women and transmen, you might want to take it for ideas. A tube can be used to aid the water flow. If it's long and hard enough, the low end can stabilize, or you can add more weight at the end. **It can also be personalized so that it makes them feel funny and meaningful.**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of investing in and using disposable pads, mats, absorbents, etc. which can be costly over time, place a pan or tub, which can be rinsed often and washed clean on occasion, strategically beside the toilet.

You might even find one that is aesthetically acceptable as well as functionally effective.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a seller of this item. I googled the issue because it does sound like a issue that impacts the dignity of both caregiver and patient.

I found the following device that may provide a solution. I hope that it helps or provide some additional ideas on solutions.

[image]

[Link to reference](https://www.ebay.com/itm/193048814145)

As for how to clean the area

> 1) a baking soda paste;

1/8 cup of baking soda, slowly add water a table spoon at a time and mix between each tablespoon, until a paste forms. You can add salt to make a more abrasive scrubbing. Then use a cleaning brush or sponge to scrub the mixture into the surface. Apply a thicker coat on grout and allow to dry. Then use a wet sponge to rub it off.

> 2) Borax is another cleaning product alternative you can likely find in any supermarket.